How do I install OpenSTLinux onto STM32MP1 series?
How do I install OpenSTLinux onto STM32MP1 series?
I have heard that I should download OpenSTLinux pre-compiled binaries, but I don't know where to find them.
I have been searching at github and found
https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/meta-st-openstlinux
I have installed the STM32CubeProgrammer. But now I'm stuck and I don't know how to flash the eMMC with OpenSTLinux at my STM32MP1 board.
Do you know how to install OpenSTLinux onto eMMC?
I have the ability to flash via USB OTG FS.

I don't see any pre-compiled binaries in that repo, just a bunch of Yocto recipes. So you'll need to figure out how to build a Yocto image. Good luck, the learning curve is steep.
